# Extending NSMutableData class

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledata

My question is simple. I want to extend the NSMutableData class in iOS and override some of the methods defined in NSMutableData. For e.g. I want to override writeToFile function with my own wrapper implementation for it. 
Is it possible to do this?

My TestNSMutableData.h

```
@interface TestNSMutableData : NSMutableData
-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString*)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;
@end
```

My TestNSMutableData.m

```
@implementation TestNSMutableData
-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString*)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile{
  //Some activity on the data and modifying it
  return [self writeToFile:path atomically:useAuxiliaryFile];
}
```

When I try to use the TestNSMutableData in one of my project like

```
TestNSMutableData myData;
myData = [TestNSMutableData alloc]init];
[myData writeToFile:path atomically:YES]
```

I get an error as follows

> NSInvalidArgumentException'- reason '*** - length only defined for abstract class. Define -[TestNSMutableData length] !

Is it possible at all to override the methods defined in Native classed for e.g. NSMutableData ?

**UPDATE**
I create NSString class category method for writeTofile

My implementation is

```
-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString*)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliary encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError**)error{


 //Manipulating NSString 
  self = manipulatedString;
  return [super writeToFile....];

}
```

I get a warning "NSObject may not respond to 'writeToFile' function. Which is technically correct as NSString is derived from NSObject and NSObject does not have writeToFile function.

What I want is to write the manipulated string in the file and not the actual string.

Is there a way to call the NSString writeToFile method from the above function.

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMutableData` is probably a [class cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844158/what-exactly-is-a-so-called-class-cluster-in-objective-c), making it a bit [hard to subclass](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html). Why not use a category to add a custom `-writeToFile` method instead?

Comment: If I add a category and the methods signature is what the native has, it gives me compilation error wherever I instantiate the TestNSMutableClass (it says Did you mean NSMutableClass)

Comment: If you add a category, there’s no `TestNSMutableData`, right? You can’t (or shouldn’t) override a method using category, you would have to add a method with a different signature. If you really need to override the original method, I’d suggest wrapping `NSMutableData` in a custom class and forwarding all calls except the overriden one. Or, even better, trying to solve your main problem in a different way.

Comment: Thanks Zoul !! I finally achieved it using the Category (I was trying to create manually rather than using XCode). Thanks again !!