# How to create custom class clusters in objective-c..?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have two classes say `A` and `B`and I want to create objects of any one of these classes depending upon some condition. Can I create a custom class cluster for this? If YES, how? I know that `NSMutableArray` also works on the same principle.

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844158/what-exactly-is-a-so-called-class-cluster-in-objective-c) question, and especially Frank C.'s answer.

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is a class cluster pattern, you can find many examples here on SO as well as on the [Apple Dev](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) pages itself.
Have a look into a simple example of this pattern given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844158/what-exactly-is-a-so-called-class-cluster-in-objective-c) by @Frank C.