# Class within class in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want similar functionality like class within a class in Objective-C.

One way is to create separate `NSObject` class but I have to create 20 classes for that.

Is there any alternative in Objective-C for Class within a Class functionality.

Like in java:

```
public class SessionDBConstants {

    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "session.db";

    public static class Grade {

        public static final String Table = "grades";
        public static final String RowId = "id";
        public static final String ScheduleID = "schedule_id";
        public static final String Level = "level";
        public static final String Label = "label";
        public static final String Thershold = "thershold";

        public static final String CreateStmt = "create table grades"
                + "(id integer primary key autoincrement, schedule_id int, level int, label varchar, thershold int )";

        public static final String DropStmt = "drop table if exists grades;";

    }
}
```

how to implement this in Objective-C?

Comment: Can you explain in somewhat details like simple example for what you want to achieve?

Comment: ok i will edit the question with code

Comment: No, Objective-C doesn't support this (it's got nothing to do with Xcode either).

Comment: i know but is there any other alternative that i can use?

Comment: Can I use structure for the same?

Comment: No a `struct` won't give you everything a `@class` will give you.  Nested-classes are really only to do with protection; and you can do the same in separate distinct classes.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain WHY you want this functionality.  There are several purported advantages of Java inner classes, but most can be had through other means.

Comment: I explain it in the question that i have to create to many NSObject classes for the same but if there is any alternative to this i will able to do in only one class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful pattern to use might be the Class Cluster described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html

There is a fantastically clear example of the concept here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2459385/346098

Answer (score 1):

**SORRY** think I'm bit off on what I thought the question meant.
In your class you can start another  @implementation

```
.h
@interface classOne : NSObject
@end
@interface classTwo : NSObject
@end

.m
@implementation classOne
@end

@implementation classTwo
@end
```

Hope it helps.
BooRanger