# Objective-C and Class Cluster pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

I have read some information about Class Cluster pattern, and understood next:

- public cluster class only provides interface without actual implementation, other classes implement it for different cases;
- it has some similarities with Abstract Factory pattern: when we call method `+classNameWith...` it depending on arguments can choose the most appropriate subclass and return it.

For example, `+[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0]`, will return implementation for storing double values.

But what i didn't understand: how works `-init...` methods of public cluster class:
`[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:1.0]`, as after calling `alloc` it already allocates instance of `NSNumber`, not it's subclass.

So, can somebody explain how actually works `alloc-init` methods of public cluster class, and when concrete subclass instantiated and returned?

Comment: You might be interested in perusing the [GNUStep version of NSNumber.m](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-base/blob/master/Source/NSNumber.m).

Comment: Josh Caswell, thanks for the great link!

Comment: I assume that you have already read [Concepts in Objective-C Programming: Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the instance you have allocated could be thrown away and replaced with a different instance. Technically, this isn't specific to class clusters and that is why when you call `super` in any `init` method you need to set the result as `self`:

```
self = [super init];
```

Comment: Moreover, the +alloc method can be overridden just like any other method. The class cluster alloc would probably return a static instance, instead of new objects being created and released every time you request a new instance.

Comment: Bored Astronaut, yes i also thought that they override alloc method, because otherwise there will be some overhead for destruction of the allocated objects.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the Abstract factory implementation for Objective C.

```
// Usage
    BrandingFactory * factory = [BrandingFactory factory:Sierra];

    UIView * view = [factory brandedView];

    UIButton * button = [factory brandedMainButton];

    UIToolbar * toolbar = [factory brandedToolbar];
____________________________________________
//  BrandingFactory.h
//  AbstractFactory

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum ouputTypes {
    Acme,
    Sierra
} OutputTypes;

@interface BrandingFactory : NSObject 
{

}

+ (BrandingFactory *) factory: (OutputTypes)type;

- (UIView *) brandedView;
- (UIButton *) brandedMainButton;
- (UIToolbar *) brandedToolbar;

@end

___________________________________________________

//  BrandingFactory.m
//  AbstractFactory

#import "BrandingFactory.h"
#import "AcmeBrandingFactory.h"
#import "SierraBrandingFactory.h"


@implementation BrandingFactory

+ (BrandingFactory *) factory:(OutputTypes)type
{
    if (type == Sierra) {
        return [[[SierraBrandingFactory alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    else if (type == Acme)
    {
        return [[[AcmeBrandingFactory alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    return nil;

}

- (UIView *) brandedView
{
    return nil;
}

- (UIButton *) brandedMainButton
{
    return nil;
}

- (UIToolbar *) brandedToolbar
{
    return nil;
}

@end

________________________________________

//  SierraBrandingFactory.h
//  AbstractFactory

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BrandingFactory.h"


@interface SierraBrandingFactory : BrandingFactory
{

}

- (UIView*) brandedView;
- (UIButton*) brandedMainButton;
- (UIToolbar*) brandedToolbar;

@end


//  SierraBrandingFactory.m
//  AbstractFactory

#import "SierraBrandingFactory.h"
#import "SierraView.h"
#import "SierraMainButton.h"
#import "SierraToolbar.h"

@implementation SierraBrandingFactory

- (UIView*) brandedView
{
    // returns a custom view for Sierra
    return [[[SierraView alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (UIButton*) brandedMainButton
{
    // returns a custom main button for Sierra
    return [[[SierraMainButton alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (UIToolbar*) brandedToolbar
{
    // returns a custom toolbar for Sierra
    return [[[SierraToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
}

@end

________________________________________
//  AcmeBrandingFactory.h
//  AbstractFactory


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BrandingFactory.h"


@interface AcmeBrandingFactory : BrandingFactory
{

}

- (UIView *) brandedView;
- (UIButton *) brandedMainButton;
- (UIToolbar *) brandedToolbar;

@end


//  AcmeBrandingFactory.m
//  AbstractFactory

#import "AcmeBrandingFactory.h"
#import "AcmeView.h"
#import "AcmeMainButton.h"
#import "AcmeToolbar.h"


@implementation AcmeBrandingFactory

- (UIView *) brandedView
{
    // returns a custom view for Acme
    return [[[AcmeView alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (UIButton *) brandedMainButton
{
    // returns a custom main button for Acme
    return [[[AcmeMainButton alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (UIToolbar *) brandedToolbar
{
    // returns a custom toolbar for Acme
    return [[[AcmeToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: As the OP points out. The two patterns are *similar* but not the same

Comment: So this is the Abstract Factory implementation. But in general they are very similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/2459385/1847511

Comment: Can you please explain the difference in few words?

Comment: The factory in a class cluster is an abstract class that produces concrete subclasses of itself. You only need to know that you are using an `NSNumber`, you don't have to know that behind the scenes you got back an instance of `NSSignedIntegerNumber` but you can still get the specific behaviour of that class. It's much more implicit since all you are doing is calling an `init` method on NSNumber and getting back a class that as is a kind of NSNumber.

Comment: You can read more about it in [Concepts in Objective-C Programming: Class Clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).