# Difference between class clusters and abstract factory in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, abstract-factory

I have read that [Obj-C class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) are an implementation of the [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Can anyone explain if there are any differences between the 2 as design patterns.  I read somewhere that there are certain restrictions on class clusters that don't apply to traditional abstract factory but it did not give more details.

Comment: *'certain restrictions on class clusters that don't apply'* -  

If you phrase your question more specifically we might be able to answer your question.

Comment: @cacau thanks, i checked that link you sent, not sure I understand it the answer fully. could you offer a lower level explanation on the differences? and an example of when you would use each one? please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2459385/839506

This may help. It has an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the limitations concern attempting to modify the Foundation class clusters rather than those you may write on your own. For example, subclassing NSDictionary (which is a Foundation class cluster) can lead to some interesting problems.

You are free to implement your own class clusters, which is fairly easy and can have a high payoff. [A class cluster is a type of abstract factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094194/1059025).