# What is NSFrozenDictionaryM?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I came across NSFrozenDictionary while debugging an app.

[image: NSFrozenDictionary]

Shared index property declared as `NSDictionary * sharedIndex = ...`

What is it? How is it different from NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: It's internal classes/wrapper. Use it as a casual `NSDictionary`. Strangely, I would have considered it as mutable (since there is a "M" at the end", but debugger treats it as a NSDictionary (not mutable), and the "frozen" tends too to say so.

Comment: I assume "M" at the end is short for implementation, maybe to explicitly differentiate it from a protocol type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is one of the concrete subclasses that is part of the `NSDictionary` [class cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844158/what-exactly-is-a-so-called-class-cluster-in-objective-c).

There is a [more academic description on Apple's documentation site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).

Essentially: don't worry about it. If you declared it as a plain `NSDictionary`, then treat it as such: an immutable dictionary. Foundation may create something else under the hood for optimization purposes, but as far as your code is concerned, it's still an immutable dictionary.

Answer (score 12):

It is an `NSMutableDictionary` marked as immutable.

One case to get `__NSFrozenDictionaryM`:

1. Have an array of mutable dictionaries:

   `NSArray *array = @[{NSMutableDictionary}, {NSMutableDictionary}, {NSMutableDictionary}]`
2. Making a two-level-deep copy of it by:

   `NSArray *res = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array copyItems:YES]`

The resulting `res` array contains immutable copies of NSMutableDictionaries in `array`, which are of type `__NSFrozenDictionaryM`. I guess this is an optimisation to avoid really copying all dictionaries in the original array.